# Issues with SVG Export from Adobe Illustrator: Unwanted Artifacts Appearing

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been experiencing some issues while exporting drawing fields from Adobe Illustrator to SVG format. When I export certain elements, the resulting SVG occasionally displays spots that resemble mold or some sort of unwanted artifact.

Image with unwanted Artifacts
[image]
Image without unwanted Artifacts
[image]

Here's a brief rundown:

Yes, there seem to be specific elements/effects in my drawing fields that cause this problem.

Can anyone suggest the optimal export settings to avoid these unwanted spots? Or has anyone else encountered and resolved a similar issue?

Comment: Hi. Did you create these yourself, or were these blurred circles from stock vector art? If the latter, then there's a strong possibility that these may have been flattened in Illustrator before export. You may have to recreate the blurred circles yourself.  Recreating them using a simple circular gradient will be quicker than trying to fix something that was flattened like that.

Comment: There's *probably* a blend mode applied to those areas in AI which is not translated to the SVG export.

Comment: @Scott, you are right. That is what happening. What settings do i need to use to correctly translate this is the question.

Comment: @BillyKerr, in AI it looks great. If i export the badge to png format everything works great. If i export it to SVG i get the blurred circles.

Comment: Fabian, first try here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21680/retain-blending-mode-after-saving-to-svg-illustrator

Comment: @Fabian - perhaps don't use a blend mode. Draw a circle and apply a circular gradient going from solid in the centre to transparent around the edge.

Comment: Does SVG support transparent gradients from Illustrator? I agree, that's an easy fix, **if** the export will support it.